# Can not click on body background image for redirect

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, background-image

I have page with centered position of content. On body (behind this div) have a background image, and when i click on visible part of image i must redirect user to other link. 
The problem is that the div is over body (and it should be that). When i click i am on padding of div. I tried with `jquery` when click on div to redirect, but every time when click it is redirect, i want only when click on image background.

```
<? php echo '<body style="background-image: url(/tv/banners/main/main_banner_68_1.jpg);" class="tm-isblog" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" id="background-body"  >';
echo '<div class="tv-content" onclick="showMsg()">';
```

here is content of page

```
<script type="application/javascript">
        function showMsg(item) {
            alert('redirect me now');
    }  </script>
```

css:

```
body{margin:0;padding:0 !important;overflow-x:hidden;width:100%;}


.tv-content{margin: auto;width: 100%;border: 0px solid green;padding: 90px 130px;overflow: hidden;}
```

Comment: sorry, i tried many things and i am forgot to copy. You can check it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I get your question correct, you want to redirect if a user clicks on the body even if the click is inside the "padding" of the container with the class .tv-content?

You could achieve this by doing the following:

```
// trigger the click event on body
$('body').on('click', function(e) {
  // get the real click target from the event object
  var elm = $(e.target); 
  // in case this element has no parents with the class, redirect 
  if (!elm.parents().hasClass('tv-content')) {
    console.log('redirect now');
  }
});
```

I made a simple [demo](https://codepen.io/webandapp/pen/ZmqJdx) for this.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you're looking for, I've fixed a few errors you had in your markup too.

Markup:

```
<?php 
echo '<body style="background-image: url(/tv/banners/main/main_banner_68_1.jpg);" class="tm-isblog" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" id="background-body">';
echo '<div class="tv-content" onClick="myFunction()"';
?>
```

Jquery:

```
function myFunction() {
// This is your alert message
var r = confirm("Do you really want to leave?");
if (r == true) {
// Where to redirect your users
window.location.href = "anotherwebpage.html";
}
else {
}
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but when click on page ( menu , images or something else) it is redirect me too ... on every click it is redirect

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to click to body. Then why are you using padding to center?
Center the content => body{min-width:100%; min-height: 100vh; *display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items:center;*}

If you want exact width like padding use *'calc' => width: calc(100% - 260px); height: calc(100% - 180px);*
Now you can click to body; You can use jQuery or just tag :
In Code Snippet

```css
html,body{
  margin:0;
  padding:0 !important;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  
  position:relative;
}

a {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

div {
  background-color: aqua;
  margin: 90px auto; 
  width: calc(100% - 260px);
  height: 100%;
  
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  
  /*decor*/
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <a href="https://www.google.com"></a>
  <div>
    some text
  </div>
</body>
```